# Difference between prefix and postfix opperand?

Tags: java, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I believe that this question is different, because the other question was asking how the numbers were being incremented inside the println().  The accepted answer in the other question was not explaining that postfix increments the value after it is printed.

I have been reading from the Big Index, and I understand how and when to use postfixes, but I had no idea that prefixes existed. What does it mean when it says that 6 gets printed twice in this code? I thought that it added to the integer.

```
class PrePostDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 3;
        i++;
        // prints 4
        System.out.println(i);
        ++i;               
        // prints 5
        System.out.println(i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(++i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(i++);
        // prints 7
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Why would it not print 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?

Comment: I believe that my question may be somewhat different, as I understand that you can increment the int inside the println()

Comment: But what I don't understand is why it says that 6 gets printed twice.

Comment: That's not true, you can use the prefix and postfix operators anywhere

Comment: Obviously you can...I was referring to the related question.

Comment: This is different because I already understand that concept, I just didn't understand why 7 was not printed when 6 was incremented, but this has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix will perform the addition/subtraction before executing the current statement of code. Postfix will perform it afterwards.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Thank you.